# percentage of a vector rounding up or down and integer division

Tags: java

I have the following code to take a percentage of 'set' and for example if 60% is entered it keeps the 9 examples of 'set' only. However, I need to modify this as if >0.5 I round the number up but if it is <0.5 I round it down. For instance 9.6 keeps the first 10 training examples while 9.4 keeps the first 9 examples.

```
public void proportion(int percentage)
{
    int noOfEx = percentage*set.size()/100; 
    root.keptEx = new Vector(set.subList(0, noOfEx));
}
```

I tried to do

```
public void proportion(int percentage)
{
    double noOfEx = percentage*set.size()/100; 
    int rounded = (int)Math.round(noOfEx);
    root.keptEx = new Vector(set.subList(0, rounded));
    System.out.println(noOfEx);
}
```

but if set.size is 16 I still get a 9 while I need a 10

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?#q=java%20round%20to%20the%20nearest%20integer

Comment: yes but I need to round up and down at the same time

Comment: First, use a double for noOfEx: `double noOfEx = percentage*set.size()/100.0;`  Then, use Math.round() to do the rounding you are looking for:  `root.keptEx = new Vector(set.subList(0, Math.round(noOfEx));`

Comment: @DannyDaglas `Math.round(noOfEx)` needs to be cast to `int`, since `noOfEx` is a `double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.round`:

```
double number = 22.5;
int rounded = (int)Math.round(number);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/YIq7IU)

Comment: I did double noOfEx = Math.round(percentage*set.size()/100); but then I can't use subList since I am getting an error that no suitable method is found for subList(int,double) .

Comment: @user4345738 Read the answer carefully. The rounded result is an int, and you should use it instead of the double.

Comment: @user4345738 Your issue is not related to rounding, it's related to integer division. If both operands are integers, the result is auto-casted to int, so you won't have decimal places. Please use `double noOfEx = percentage*set.size()/100.0;` That `100.0` means "take the 100 as double", so it will perform a double division.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! will update question title